# Convert Intel HEX file to binary file

Tags: python, binary, hex

I have a Intel HEX file and I want to have a binary file.
How, in python ?

I think use the [binascii module](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html) but I don't know what function is the most appropriate.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be interested in [the IntelHex python lib](https://pypi.org/project/IntelHex).

Comment: Oh, yes ! That's all I needed! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have a string of hex, you can decode it using the `decode` method. For instance,

```
>>> s = '0001020304'
>>> s.decode('hex')
'\x00\x01\x02\x03'
```

Comment: Answer is missing the point totally: Intel HEX file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX is something totally different from plain hex string ( similar problem as "I want to show content of binary executable file, like test.com" answered by " binary 10101 can be shown as 21 dec or 15 hex )