# Convert intel hex string to normal hex in java

Tags: java, hex

I have a string that is in **intel hex format** and it needs to be converted to hex format and then from there to decimal. The data is sent from a gps device.

This is the result I should get

```
Intel hex  : 85630800 (input)

device hex : 00086385 

decimal    : 549765
```

How can I get this ?

I have tried to convert intel hex to binary(as intel hex is ascii rep of binary) and binary to hex but it does not give me the value 00086385(hex) for input 85630800(intelhex)

I am now looking at this library Java Intel hex parser https://github.com/j123b567/java-intelhex-parser

But this talks about converting a file in intel hex to binary format not strings. I am trying to see if I can use the code(part or full) but it seems really overkill.

Also looking at [Convert Intel HEX file to binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754487/convert-intel-hex-file-to-binary-file) but it is for python .

Once I get it converted to normal hex, I can use Integer.ParseInt() or Long.ParseInt() for decimal.

But I am not able to convert the intel hex string to normal hex format. In there a way to convert intel hex string to normal hex string or value in java ?

**Update**

After reading the answers , I realize the correct question to ask was how to convert Little endian hex strings to Big endian . The documentation for a GPS device I had, specified the format as **intel hex**(maybe because Intel based processors are little endians) which threw me off from understanding the format of data I had.

Comment: When you say "intel hex format" you just mean "little-endian" right? You can either just swap the bytes in the string, or parse it as an integer in its current format and switch the bytes in the integer. What have you *tried* in either respect?

Comment: @JonSkeet to tell you the truth i do not know !! the documentation I have says that a  particular value is in intel hex format(85630800) and its normal hex value is this(00086385 ) and decimal value is this(549765) . I need to do the conversion in java code. I am thinking intel hex means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX.

Comment: Okay. Well, as I said - you can do this either way. Have you tried *anything* yet? Just string manipulation will be somewhat ugly but work (just four calls to substring, concatenating the results together...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A capability of [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) can help, a class one should read the javadoc of.

```
int input = (int) Long.parseLong("85630800", 16); // 0x85630800
int result = Integer.reverseBytes(input);
```

As the hex string can be larger than the *signed* int value, better use long.

---

***Addendum***

Since java 8: [parseUnsignedInt](http://com.nextlevel.iMsbBilling.implementation.processes.contract.UpdateContractStateDelegate).

```
int input = Integer.parseUnsignedInt("85630000", 16);
```

Comment: Nice, this seems as the optimal solution. However, what about bigger hex values? Won't "FFFFFFFF" overflow it?

Comment: That's the right solution for his problem. Should have had myself a look into the API for this `reverseBytes` stuff. ;-)

Comment: @Master Intel architecture = little Endian, java BigEndian. The example shows 4 bytes being reversed (java int); 2 (short) or 8 (long) would be possible too. Little endian is about the least significant byte coming first, at index 0. For other sizes of bytes with embedded 2/4/8 numbers, use a ByteBuffer with `order(LITTLE_ENDIAN)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I see. I am not familiar with `ByteBuffer` but if I ever have a similar problem I will have it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert a little-endian hex string into a big-endian hex string, you might start with following snippet. Depending on what you need to solve in the big picture some tuning might be needed.

```
String s = "85630800";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
for (int i = s.length() - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
    sb.append(s.charAt(i)).append(s.charAt(i+1));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

**output**

```
00086385
```

Comment: pffff, I was about to post it! :P Let me add the hex to int conversion `Integer.parseInt(sb.toString(), 16);`

Comment: On second thoughts, better convert it with `Long.parseLong(sb.toString(), 16)` to avoid overflows.