# sending a ihex (intel Hex) file over UDP using python Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, udp, link-local

I am working with **IPv6 and UDP sockets** using **python-2.7**. I am particularly focusing on **IPv6 Multicasting** `ff02::1` where every Link-Local address device (with `fe80::`) responds to queries from a central server entity.

I have Microcontrollers attached to these devices which need a program in the form of `.ihex` (**Intel Hex**). A snippet of the file is as below:

```
:103100005542200135D0085A8245381131400031EE
:103110003F4002000F9308249242381120012F8370
:103120009F4F1E390011F8233F4036000F930724AC
```

I thing the way to go about it is using `struct` and using functions like `pack` and `unpack` but I am not sure whether sending such an **ihex** file which is in the size of few **Kbs** would solve the purpose.

Can I do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from struct import pack, unpack
import socket
.   # Create a UDP socket and Bind it..
.
myHexCode = open("Filename.ihex")
dataToSend = struct.pack('Paramaters for packing', myHexCode)
.
. Send data to socket..
```

What will be the Packing Parameters ? (should I do `!` or Big or small Endian `>` or `<` for the Hex File?)

#### Note

- I cannot use `scp` nor `sftp` since both these protocols work on **TCP** and do not support Multicasting and I am working in an environment where Losses in the Network may be higher (*Wireless Medium*)
- Also should I convert the **Intel Hex** file to binary as suggested from this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754487/convert-intel-hex-file-to-binary-file) and then pack the binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UDP with multicast to send a file to multiple consumers seems fraught with issues -- unless the entire file fits within a single packet. UDP packets may be dropped/discarded for a number of reasons and you've already said the network is lossy. You'll need to have a way for each consumer to track and notify the sender about dropped packets.

That being said, it's certainly doable. One idea: Construct an initial packet that you multicast several times, perhaps with random delays in between (in an attempt to ensure that all stations receive it). This initial packet saying in effect like "About to send new program - expect N subsequent record packets").

Then send the N packets, perhaps twice each. Put an identifying serial number in each data packet, and have the consumers track which ones they receive. After some delay (or when all have been received), have each consumer respond with a status packet saying either "I got all N packets" or "I didn't get records 5, 98, 144, and 3019" (or whatever scheme is appropriate based on lossiness).

Then the sender can collect these lost record IDs and resend those until all consumers are satisfied they have received the entire file.

For packing them into the datagrams, I don't think it matters whether you send "intel hex" or binary. In either case, you will want to send them as a stream of bytes. Binary will be smaller and hence take fewer packets, but there's no other difference in the process of sending them. For the same reason, the byte ordering you select won't make a difference. For simple byte streams, you don't need to use `struct` to pack them at all. You can just send them.

> Note: python3 distinguishes between `bytes` and `str` types so you would need to open the file in "binary" mode for this to remain true with python3.

However, if as suggested above, you end up sending a serial number in each packet, that serial number will need to be formatted somehow. You can format a number as an ascii string and no `struct.pack` is needed. Or if you format it in binary, you'd need to select a packing format. Conventionally networking packets use "network byte order" (which is actually the same as big-endian) but that is only a convention.

If I were doing it, I might structure each record with:

- record type (binary, one byte -- distinguishing this is a data packet)
- record ID (binary, two bytes -- serial number [or larger depending on
  how large the files are])
- record data length (binary, two bytes indicating length of record data field)
- record data (binary, N bytes)

You could then create the payload with something like this:

```
payload = struct.pack("!BHH", record_type, record_id, len(record_data))
          + record_data
```

Here we're creating a 5 byte string with `struct.pack` containing the "header" fields (packed using network byte order), then simply appending the record_data which is already a byte string.

Comment: so I am actually using something called as the [Trickle Algorithm](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6206) which is a timer for random time period generation and sending data out as you said. I also initially created a simplex version of the so called __HEADER__ with `MSGVERSION` and according to the algorithm it works I will definitely give your Idea about getting some form of feedback from the receivers. 

Thanks for the Idea.

Comment: So I have a query as to which parameter should is use to unpack the complete ihex file? 

I am not converting the __ihex__ to binary as of now and am completely sending it as it is on the payload. 
I have __MSGVERSION__+ __DATALEN__ as packed parameters and then concatenated by ihex file as it is.

but i still keep getting `struct.error: need a 'str' of Length X` which is actually telling me that I am on the ihex file but I cannot parse it.. Any way around this?

Comment: I assume you're using python on the receiving side too? Probably you just need to use `struct.unpack_from` which allows you to pull the initial few header bytes but doesn't require you to use the entire buffer.  So, something like:  `version, data_len = struct.unpack_from("!BH", buffer);   ....     data = buffer[3:]; ....`

Comment: works like a charm @Gil thanks for the great idea. Have accepted it as a standard Answer

Comment: Hi @Gil now comes the tricky part, Now my __ihex__ files are actually in the order of `~100Kb` so that means the UDP payload wont take it and I need to split the file in order to fit them. 

I found `split` on Ubuntu that does the job for you. How do I kind of put these split files in to a Queue or a Buffer to send them out accordingly on UDP packets (considering the fact that each Chunk will be less than 65535 bytes)

Comment: I'd read the entire file in one fell swoop with `file_obj.read()`. Then split it up with slicing: First slice: buffer[0:1400], second is [1400:2800], etc. If it were me, I would keep the slice size (hence datagram size) below your network MTU (I used 1400 but you could probably go up to about 1472 on standard network). UDP will allow you to send a datagram that is up to 64K in length, but if larger than the MTU, that will actually be broken up into multiple IP fragments (packets). If even one packet of the group is lost, they'll all be discarded.

Comment: This is a nice discussion of UDP issues and fragmentation: https://notes.shichao.io/tcpv1/ch10/

Comment: Hi @Gil yes in fact I did plan to keep the payload lower than 1500 Bytes due to the IP fragmentation. I did some research and there was something that caught my interest was [Fountain Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_code) where instead of asking an ACK I could use some Forward Error Correcting schemes in packets. This turns out to be interesting when you find something called as __Luby Transform Codes__ and some enthusiasts have done [some work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511644/how-do-i-test-my-implementation-of-lt-codes)

Comment: Also I am curious as to which routing protocol do you use in your case after splitting your data and then sending it out in the network?

Comment: @Shan-Desai Disclaimer: I haven't actually done this. It's all just theoretical to me. (Also, issues of routing seem completely orthogonal to the question here so I wonder if I'm missing the point.)

Comment: no I was just curious ! Good I will definitely let you know if things go according to the theoretical aspect. Will keep in touch. Thanks.